# Can't get ModRewrite to work at all under Ubuntu

Tags: mod-rewrite, ubuntu, apache2

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong with ModRewrite. rewrite.load and proxy.load have been loaded with a2enmod and both appear under modules enabled. I tried to set up the most basic ModRewrite scenario I could think of but it doesn't redirect at all, I still get the same 404 error messages had they not even been enabled.

Here's what my directory looks like

```
/var/www
    /test
        showimage.php //showimage.jpg should redirect here
        test.html //a page with a <img> tag that points to showimage.jpg
        .htaccess //I've tried putting this in /var/www but it doesn't work either
```

Here's my .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /var/www/test
RewriteRule ^showimage.jpg?(.*) http://localhost/test/showimage.php?$1
RewriteRule ^test.jpg http://localhost/test/showimage.php
```

Here's test.html

```
<html>
<body>
<img alt="didn't work" src="showimage.jpg?thing=thing1" />
</body>
</html>
```

Here's showimage.php

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

$im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 30);

$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);

if(isset($_GET["thing"])) {
    $text = $_GET["thing"];
}
else {
    $text = "none set by GET params";
}

$font = "some.ttf";

imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 11, 21, $grey, $font, $text);
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);

imagejpeg($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Finally, here's my only currently enabled site on apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Does anybody know why this setup for a modrewrite isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `AllowOverride None` in all relevant directories.  I believe you need `AllowOverride FileInfo Options` (at a minimum) for the relevant directory, which in this case appears to be `/var/www`.

**Edit:**

In case it wasn't clear, I'm referring to your virtual host configuration, not anything in .htaccess.

Comment: YES! Thanks a lot, man. Also, I had to change the regex on the first rewrite to: RewriteRule ^showimage.jpg(.*) http://localhost/test/showimage.php$1. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

change `AllowOverride None` in `AllowOverride All` and restart your server.